# Small vertices with tkz-graph

Tags: tkz-graph

I would like to draw small (although visible) vertices with package `tkz-graph`.  I tried with MinSize, but this is a lower bound on the size, and I am looking for an upper bound.  In the following example, it seems that when MinSize is below the lower bound that is in the package, no further reducction occurs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\begin{document}
     \foreach \x in {10,...,1}{\SetVertexSimple[MinSize=\x pt] \tikz \Vertex{A};}
\end{document}
```

Comment: \def\VertexInnerSep{0pt} will fix it.  There may be a way to do this using \SetVertexSimple, but I can't read French.

Comment: @Kormylo:  Why did't you post your solution as an answer?

Comment: Mine was only a partial solution.

Comment: @Kormylo:  I would accept it because you gave the key point (that inner sep should be used).  BTW, finally I used `\tikzset` to set both inner sep and minimum size.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to override the default `inner sep` and make it `0pt`. For this, there are two options:

- Redefining `\VertexInnerSep` to make it `0pt` as suggested in [`a comment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266689/small-vertices-with-tkz-graph#comment639358_266689).
- Using the `VertexStyle` style to append there the option.

An example showing both options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\begin{document}

{% to keep the change local
\renewcommand\VertexInnerSep{0pt}
     \foreach \x in {10,...,1}{\SetVertexSimple[MinSize=\x pt] \tikz \Vertex{A};}
}

\foreach \x in {10,...,1}{\SetVertexSimple[MinSize=\x pt] \tikz[VertexStyle/.append style={inner sep=0pt}
] \Vertex{A};}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What if I don't want to use the `Simple` style?  As soon as I use `\SetVertexSimple`, it seems to invoke the `simple` style, and, in particular, I cannot specify the color of edges and such.